# ANTLR3 not ignoring comments that begin at the first character of a file

Tags: comments, antlr3

Sorry if any terminology is off, just started using antlr recently.

Here's the antlr grammar that ignores multi-line comments:

```
COMMENT     : '/*' .* '*/';
SPACE       : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | COMMENT)+ {$channel = HIDDEN;} ;
```

Here's a comment beginning at the first character of a file I'd like to compile:

```
/* 
    This is a comment
*/
```

Here's the error I get:

```
[filename] line 252:0 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'
[filename] line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '*'
```

However, if I put a space in front of the comment, like so:

```
 /* 
    This is a comment
*/
```

It compiles fine. Any ideas?

Comment: We need the full grammar to see what's wrong. Also, usually the comment rule is made non-greedy to avoid consuming all input between two multiline comments.

Answer (score 0):

For ignoring multilines comments:

```
ML_COMMENT
    :   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
```

EDIT:

Maybe it's not because of your LEXER but because of your Parser. From lexer, with $channel=HIDDEN you are telling all these elements not to be passed to Parser. This is why parser finds EOF at first. You are sending nothing!

If you write a whitespace as the first character, parser receives something and it's able to process an input...

This should be your issue!!

I hope this would help you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Again, the issue only arises if the comment begins at the first character of the file. It's almost as if the first character '/' is ignored by the parser and all other characters '*' ' ' 'comment', etc are treated as tokens. I'll provide some more detail later, right now I'm busy with a separate project.

Comment: oh!! I made a revision to the question and an idea came to me... I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the revision! However, I'm still a little confused. As you can see in my original post, { $channel=HIDDEN; } is present for whitespace also... why would the parser receive an input for whitespace which is HIDDEN but not a comment? For the record, I also tried "skip();" instead of "$channel=HIDDEN;" and I get the same issue.

Comment: I know what you mean, and you are right. Is because of that why I'd like to see your parser. I'm still thinking that the problem is there, not here in the Lexer ;)

Comment: Oh, for sure. I generated my parser automatically though by ANTLR, though. It's a java file named [language]parser.java. Is that where I should look for the trouble or am I still completely misunderstanding the issue?